# How to store a result of type integer array from database to an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, database, postgresql

I'm using postgresql as a database and I have a column called mealsIds it's type is array of integers.

I'm making the following SQL query.

```
        // Specify connection
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(
            "Server=127.0.0.1;" +
            "User Id=username;" +
            "Password=password;" +
            "Database=db;" +
            "Port=3500");
        conn.Open();

        // Define a query
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand($"SELECT catsids FROM restaurants WHERE id = {Properties.Settings.Default.ResId.ToString()}", conn);

        // Execute a query
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {

            /*

           I WANT TO INSERT CODE HERE

            */

        }

        // Close connection
        conn.Close();
```

now I know that the result is an array of integers, and I want to store it in an array so I can use the values in it.

any idea how to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a direct [mapping](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html) from PG array to C# array. You can simply cast the returned object to an array

```
        int[] result;

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            result = (int[])dr.GetValue(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
while(dr.Read())
    {

        int newInt = int.Parse(dr["catsids"].ToString());
        //push to list or array here e.g. 
        myList.Add(newInt);

    }
```

Comment: I'm getting this exception Can't cast database type integer[] to Int32

Comment: and what if try to parse int from strings? `int.Parse(dr["catsids"].ToString())` @JohnSmith

Comment: no it won't work, you see the result is on field and it's value is this [1,2,3,4]

Comment: The dirty solution may look like `dr["catsids"].ToString().Replace("[",string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty).Split(",").Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();`

Comment: thank you very much for trying so hard to solve my problem, but I'm sorry it didn't work, appreciate it bro